# Laravel 10x: How to access env variable inside raw HTML?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a `blade page` that shows a HTML content that comes from my `Database`:

```
{!! $htmlContent !!}
```

This code render the HTML very well.

But inside that variable, I'm using a blade code like this:

```
<a href="{{ env('app_url') }}/shares"><img src="{{ asset('asset/img/shares.png') }}" /></a>
```

The problem is that both the link (which doesn't work) and the images don't appear.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You cannot use the [`env()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-env) helper if you are caching config, it will return `null` every time (read the documentation), but you can use the [`config()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-config) helper!

Comment: @Sudo Sur change the `env('app_url')` to `config('app.url')`. Your `asset/img/shares.png` is in `public` folder?

Comment: @francisco yes is in my public folder.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this, you can use the str_replace function to replace these Blade directives with their actual values before displaying the HTML content. Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
// Get the HTML content from the database
$htmlContent = // Fetch your HTML content from the database here

// Replace Blade directives with their actual values
$htmlContent = str_replace('{{ env('app_url') }}', config('app.url'), $htmlContent);
$htmlContent = str_replace('{{ asset('asset/img/shares.png') }}', asset('asset/img/shares.png'), $htmlContent);

// Display the HTML content
{!! $htmlContent !!}
```